# Strange behaviour by heuristics when solving a CSP

Tags: prolog, clpfd, eclipse-clp

Consider the following puzzle:

[image: Kakurasu]

A cell is either marked or unmarked. Numbers along the right and bottom side of the puzzle denote the total sum for a certain row or column. Cells contribute (if marked) to the sum in its row and column: a cell in position `(i,j)` contributes `i` to the column sum and `j` to the row sum. For example, in the first row in the picture above, the 1st, 2nd and 5th cell are marked. These contribute `1 + 2 + 5` to the row sum (thus totalling 8), and 1 each to their column sum.

I've written a solver in ECLiPSe CLP. It works perfectly, but it exhibits very strange behaviour for different value/variable choice methods and I have no idea why. (Note: each field in the puzzle is a decision variable with domain [0,1], 1 if marked, 0 otherwise. Constraints are obvious.)

If I use input_order (see [search/6](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/search-6.html)), first_fail, occurences or max_constrained, puzzles solve almost instantly with little memory usage. If I use anti_first_fail, largest or smallest, puzzles may take several minutes to complete **and may eat up to 16GB ram**. Why? Why do most constraints remain active for so long for these methods?

Why is there a difference between e.g. smallest and first_fail? If the domain consists of only 2 elements, and all variables have the same domain, then first_fail, anti_first_fail, largest, smallest and most_constrained should be equivalent, no? Removal of one value in the domain will attach a single value to that variable, so no more propagation is required. So search in this case will always deal with variables whose domain consists of exactly 2 items. No?